# How to debug a plugin / gem? (with useful notes to setup and use ruby-debug gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-debug

Is there a way like how we debug models / controllers with logger.debug? Or even a better method?

Thank you!

**Edit 1**

Using [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug/home-page.html) seems like a steep learning curve for me, could anyone point me something similar to logger.debug, perhaps?

**Edit 2**

Alright, I think I started to get a grasp on ruby-debug.

Some useful notes for newbies to setup & use ruby-debug:

> ```
> gem install ruby-debug
> in config/environments/development.rb add
> ```
>
> include 'ruby-debug'
>
> ```
> then just above the code you want to debug add:
>
> debugger
>
> if you need to debug third party plugin / gem, use
>
> include 'ruby-debug'
> debugger
>
> just use ruby script/server to run, no need to add --debugger
> ```

**Edit 3**

This plugin really helps me out in understanding the flow of Rails application. I highly recommend this to any newbies going pro!

Simply setup ruby-debug, then put debugger code anywhere in your controller under the action your application requested. You will then find great revelation!

Comment: Yea, using a command-line debugger is definitely a learning process, and ruby-debug is certainly no Visual Studio/XCode/etc for debugging (of course, those tools do not work with Ruby--although I bet Radrails has a debugger), but it's a huge plus over printing/logging values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend you learn to use [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html). You can install it by doing:

```
gem install ruby-debug
```

You can then add a `debugger` statement to your code either in the plugin code or where your code calls the plugin, step through it, and see what's going wrong.

I also personally use these settings which makes it a bit easier to use - put them in a `~/.rdebugrc` file.

```
set autoeval
set autolist
set autoreload
```

Comment: I tried using it for a set of test script inside the plugin (by running ctrl + R in Textmate), it returned NoMethodError: undefined method `logger' for true:TrueClass what should I do now?

Comment: You can't use `Cmd+R` from Textmate with `rdebug` - using the debugger is interactive, so you need an interactive prompt. Run your test script in Terminal with the `rdebug` command. You can also run it with plain ruby if you `require 'ruby-debug'` (rubygems will also need to be loaded for that to work).

Comment: Here's a screencast which covers using ruby-debug in a Rails app: http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug