# How to debug a plugin or gem using ruby-debug gem, where the part I wanted to debug started from test scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For example I have this gem called Authlogic-openid, that plugin is outdated, no longer supported, and broken (let me know if you know any alternative by the way).

I wanted to make sure the test runs by keying ctrl+R on vendor/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/test/acts_as_authentic_test.rb

[Please do not attempt to try my steps below, the gem itself was already broken apart so I had to earlier fix up some paths and required libraries... just imagine them in your head]

At first it returned

```
LoadError: no such file to load — ruby-debug
```

So I commented the line #3 in test_helper.rb, one that reads:

```
require "ruby-debug"
```

then I installed ruby-debug gem by

```
gem install ruby-debug
```

Then I added this into environment.rb

```
  config.gem 'ruby-debug'
```

**Question #1: Are my steps above correct to start my Gem debugging quest?**

Alright, so now the line I wanted to debug is in   vendor/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/lib/authlogic_openid/acts_as_authentic.rb line #157 (or around it) which reads:

```
  session_class.controller.params[:open_id_complete] && session_class.controller.params[:for_model]
```

So I typed "debugger" on top of it, it now reads:

```
debugger
session_class.controller.params[:open_id_complete] && session_class.controller.params[:for_model]
```

Then when I pressed ctrl + R again on vendor/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/test/acts_as_authentic_test.rb, I got this output:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Please update config/database.yml to use 'database' instead of 'dbfile'. (called from parse_sqlite_config! at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:35)
Loaded suite /Volumes/Data/work/ror/user_manager/vendor/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/test/acts_as_authentic_test
Started
E 
Finished in 0.009325 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_password_not_required_on_create(ActsAsAuthenticTest):


NoMethodError: undefined method `logger' for true:TrueClass
method debugger in debugger.rb at line 6
method openid_complete? in acts_as_authentic.rb at line 157
method authenticate_with_openid in acts_as_authentic.rb at line 83
method save in acts_as_authentic.rb at line 73
method test_password_not_required_on_create in acts_as_authentic_test.rb at line 16
method __send__ in setup_and_teardown.rb at line 62
method run in setup_and_teardown.rb at line 62

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

**Question #2: Are my steps correct to debug the code? Why did I get the error undefined method 'logger'?**

**Bonus Question: Why do I get that deprecation warning? How to fix it?**

my database.yml file as follows:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql
# On Mac OS X:
#   sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
# On Mac OS X Leopard:
#   sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
#       This sets the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to your native architecture
# On Windows:
#   gem install mysql
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install MySQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: user_manager_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: oisadj
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: user_manager_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: oisadj
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: user_manager_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your testing server with the `--debugger` flag.

From the Rails README file:

> Debugger support is available through the debugger command when you start your Mongrel or
>   Webrick server with --debugger. This means that you can break out of execution at any point
>   in the code, investigate and change the model, AND then resume execution!
>   You need to install [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug/home-page.html) to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'.

---

Regarding the deprecation warning.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Please update config/database.yml to use 'database' instead of 'dbfile'.

It seems you use SQLite. You just need to replace the `dbfile` line in your `config/database.yml` with the `database` and the warning should gone.

Comment: How do I use --debugger when I'm using textmate's ctrl + R ?

Comment: I don't have dbfile line in my database.yml, anywhere else I should be looking at?

Comment: Oh, I don't know much about Textmate. I tend to launch server from the plain old terminal using the `script/server --debugger` command. 

It's strange. Could you paste your `database.yml`?

Comment: Yes, I do also launch server by using terminal. My question was what to do if I want to run the test? not the site, but the test, the one when you do either ruby test_file.rb -v from terminal, or ctrl + R from Textmate.

Comment: And database.yml pasted above

Comment: About the deprecation warning: open the `vendor/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/test/test_helper.rb` and find `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3", :dbfile => ":memory:")`. Just replace `:dbfile` with `:database`.

Comment: If you want to run the test, you need to use it like this: `rdebug test_helper.rb`. Maybe the ruby-debug cheatsheet will also help you: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rdebug/